# Cannot compile .cpp file externally for Webots with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, webots

I'm trying to build a C++ program for Webots.

So first, I just pressed File -> New -> New Robot Controller menu and made everything default except the language, which I chose C++.

Then, Webots generated me my_controller.cpp and Makefile inside a new folder my_controller.

Because I wanted to use other tools as my text editor instead of the one that is incorporated in Webots, I chose to build externally.

When I tried to build it by typing `%WEBOTS_HOME%\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe` **INSIDE my_controller folder externally using command prompt**, it told me this:

`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

Surprisingly, when I pressed the button below, it successfully generated `build` folder and `my_controller.exe`:

[Gear-like icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCxDb.png)

Is it possible to build cpp inside vscode? If so, how?

FYI:

When I uncommented line 42 and replaced with `CXX_SOURCES = my_controller.cpp`,
I got the error message that it can't create build/release/my_controller.o when I executed `%WEBOTS_HOME%\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe`.

So I retried make command above after creating empty build/release folder, and I got this:

```
# updating my_controller.d
# compiling my_controller.cpp
# linking my_controller.exe
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/release/my_controller.o:my_controller.cpp:(.text.startup+0x29): undefined reference to `webots::Robot::Robot()'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/release/my_controller.o:my_controller.cpp:(.text.startup+0x30): undefined reference to `webots::Robot::getBasicTimeStep() const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [D:/Webots/resources/Makefile.include:576: build/release/my_controller.exe] Error 1
```

About my environment, I have installed MinGW in D:\MinGW, installed Webots in D:\Webots, but I don't know what's causing my problem.

Comment: Where are the `webots::Robot::Robot()` and `webots::Robot::getBasicTimeStep()` functions defined (implemented)? In which source file? Do you remember to build with that source file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using default Makefile, which includes %WEBOTS_HOME%/resources/Makefile.include.
I'm not used to reading complex Makefile, but it seems it includes %WEBOTS_HOME%/include/controller/cpp so it should be OK

Comment: I'm guessing that the missing definitions are in some Webots library that you are supposed to link with but haven't.

Comment: What you really need to do is look at the `%WEBOTS_HOME%/resources/Makefile.include` to see how it is supposed to be customised, or look at the Webots documentation to see how you are supposed to do this. It doesn't sound like you are doing anything particularly unusual, so the documentation should cover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read documentation carefully and found msys2 is necessary for building
- Install `msys2` from [here](https://www.msys2.org/)
- `pacman -S make` and `pacman -S gcc`
- Add `{path_to_msys64}\usr\bin` (e.g. `D:\msys64\usr\bin`) to Windows PATH

Above worked perfectly!

Thank you [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) and [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) :)